# Interfacing optical mouse with arduino

Tags: usb, shields, mouse

I have a USB mouse which I am using to measure distance travelled by my bot for a project. I followed [this blog](https://www.instructables.com/id/Optical-Mouse-Odometer-for-Arduino-Robot/) to get the optical sensor from the mouse from the arduino and interface it with the arduino. In that blog, the USB wire has been removed and the 4 pins (VCC,GND and 2 data) are connected to the arduino

However,I found the code to not be very robust as the mouse doesn't always establish Serial communication with the arduino.

I have a USB host shield for the arduino. Is there any library which will let me get the x and y coordinates of the mouse using the USB protocol?

And if not, then is there a more stable library which will be more robust than the one used in thr blog linked above?

Comment: Serial communication with an USB mouse? Really? A mouse is normally a HID device. I know no mouse, that implements a serial interface. Please show us your code

Comment: Are you sure that mouse you are using in your project is PS2/2 compatible?

Comment: @chrisl yes..I followed https://www.instructables.com/id/Optical-Mouse-Odometer-for-Arduino-Robot/ this

Comment: Yes it is PS2/2 compatible

Comment: https://github.com/felis/USB_Host_Shield_2.0 is the library for the USB host shield.